# how to write and read unicode to json file in python

Tags: python, json, unicode, jupyter

I am trying save the  Dictionary type of my data to the json file of txt file using python3.
Example the form of my data like this:

```
listdic = []
dic1 = {"id": 11106, "text": "*Kỹ_năng đàm_phán* , thuyết_phục"}
dic2 = {"id": 11104, "text": "*Ngoại_hình ưa_nhìn* , nhanh_nhẹn , giao_tiếp tốt"}
dic3 = {"id": 10263, "text": "giao_tiếp tốt"}

listdic.append(dic1)
listdic.append(dic2)
listdic.append(dic3)
```

[image]

And i want it be saved to my json file like this:

[image]

i readed some solution on internet and i tried:

```
f = open("job_benefits.json", "a", encoding= 'utf-8')

for i in listdic:
    i = json.dumps(i)
    f.write(i + '\n')
f.close()
```

but the result i have is like this:

[image]

and then i try to read file and this is my the result:

```
f = open("job_benefits.json", "r", encoding= 'utf-8')

listdic = f.readlines()
for i in listdic:
    print(i)
```

[image]

That not the way write and read the data to json file i want and some body can help to solve this case ??
Thank you very muck and sorry about my grammar !

Comment: Note that what you see are unicode escapes which are perfectly fine for JSON. Load the file as a JSON instead of plain text and you get the initial input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting readable text from a large json file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60978856/getting-readable-text-from-a-large-json-file-in-python)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi thank you so much !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python JSON and Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9693699/python-json-and-unicode)

Answer (score 4):

You are saving the file with the json module and reading it back as text, and not trying to decode the json data read. So, all characters escape-encoded to prevent information loss remain escape-encoded.

You can force json to ouptut utf-8 encoding, insteading of automatically escapping all non-ASCII characters by passing `dumps` or `dump` the `ensure_ascii=False` argument:

```py
f = open("job_benefits.json", "a", encoding= 'utf-8')

for i in listdic:
    i = json.dumps(i, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.write(i + '\n')
f.close()
```

*or*  decoding from JSON after you read your lines back:

```
import json 

f = open("job_benefits.json", "r", encoding= 'utf-8')

listdic = f.readlines()
for i in listdic:
    print(json.loads(i))
```